# Define the relation $\sim$on $\mathbb{Z}$ by $a \sim b$ if and only if $5a \equiv 2b \pmod{3}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Define the relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ by $a \sim b$ if and only if $5a \equiv 2b \pmod{3}$.

Prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{Z}$.
Identify the distinct equivalence classes on $\mathbb{Z}/\sim$.

How can I prove something like this? Do I need to prove something for reflexiveness, symmetry, and transitivity?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but if i do the answer is yes. Proving that ~ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive is exactly how you should prove this.

Comment: Show that $a\sim b$ iff $a\equiv b\pmod 3$.

Comment: So to prove, say reflexiveness, would I choose a number "a" in Z and prove that "b" could be equal to "a"?

Comment: reflexive means $a\sim a$ so you need to show that $5a \equiv 2a \pmod{3}$

Comment: @Bradly: have you *read* Arturo's answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to "prove something".

To show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, you need to prove that it is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. That is, you need to prove that:

1. For every $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $a\sim a$ is true. Since "$x\sim y$" means "$5x\equiv 2y\pmod{3}$", then that means that you need to prove that for every $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $5a\equiv 2a\pmod{3}$ is true.
2. For every $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, if $a\sim b$ is true, then $b\sim a$ is true. If you are unsure what this means, then "unpack" the meaning of "$a\sim b$" and of "$b\sim a$" the way I did above.
3. For every $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$, if $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$ are both true, then $a\sim c$ is true.

That will prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

Then you need to think about the equivalence classes. That is, given $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, what is $[a]=\{b\in\mathbb{Z}\mid a\sim b\}$, the set of all integers that are related to $a$? The different sets you get this way are the equivalence classes of $\mathbb{Z}/\sim$.